# Retrieving data using JSON-P

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am a newbie to javascript. I am experimenting with the below code for retrieving cross site data.

How can I do this code work, e.g. I want each family member is alerted to the screen.

Thank you for your help.

The code is amended like this and the alert says [object Object], do you know what this means??:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      // LOOP THROUGH EACH FAMILY MEMBER AND DO STUFF!
      alert(mValue)
    });
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `console.dir(oData)` to view all properties. You will see quickly then what you need to loop

Comment: Remove the `$()` invocation around the array - pass it directly into `$.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to wrap the `oData` with jQuery in your $.each

so, instead of

```
$.each($(oData['ops:patent-family']['ops:family-member']),
```

you want:

```
$.each(oData['ops:patent-family']['ops:family-member'],
```

Also - you have to go down a level with the returned json (there is a first 'ops:world-patent-data' level), which will look something more like:

```
if(oData['ops:world-patent-data'] && 
  oData['ops:world-patent-data']['ops:patent-family'] && 
  oData['ops:world-patent-data']['ops:patent-family']['ops:family-member']){

  $.each(oData['ops:world-patent-data']['ops:patent-family']['ops:family-member'],
    function(iIndex, mValue) {
      // LOOP THROUGH EACH FAMILY MEMBER AND DO STUFF!
      console.log(iIndex, mValue)
    });

}
```

---

Another completely different way to do this is by using jquery deferreds syntax and using .pipe to transform the data - might be a bit cleaner than the `if`

```
var sUrl =  "http://ops.epo.org/2.6.2/rest-services/family/publication/docdb/EP.1000000.A1/.js?callback=?";    

$.getJSON(sUrl)
.pipe(function(data){
    try{
        return data['ops:world-patent-data']['ops:patent-family']['ops:family-member'];
    } catch(e){
        return [];
    }
})
.then(function(members){
    $.each(members, function(iIndex, mValue){ 
        console.log(iIndex, mValue)
    })
})
```

Comment: I can not retrieve any data also this way.

Comment: strange. I've just added a different way of doing it if you want to give that a go?

Comment: I amended your code like this and I receive [object Object] alert:                                                    $.each(oData['ops:world-patent-data']['ops:patent-family']['ops:family-member'],
    function(iIndex, mValue) {
      // LOOP THROUGH EACH FAMILY MEMBER AND DO STUFF!
      alert(mValue)
    })

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do inline script creation:

```
    function myCallback(response) {
        // Your stuff goes here.
    }
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://ops.epo.org/2.6.2/rest-services/family/publication/docdb/EP.1000000.A1/.js?callback=myCallback";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's $.ajax method allows you to specify a dataType for the request. If you specify JSONP, it will create the callback for you so you don't have to worry about that.

It goes like this:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // do stuff with data here
    }
});​
```

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating that with the data you needed:
http://jsfiddle.net/PPVX3/

Right now it's logging the data to the console, if you're using Chrome or Firefox you can use the developer tools to see the console log.